# Is there a liquibase equivalent for Marklogic

Tags: maven, liquibase, marklogic

Marklogic is an XML db that is used for storage and retrieval of XML based content.
Analogus to PL/SQL for Oracle, Marklogic uses XQuery to procedurally manipulate XML.

I'm trying to control XQuery scripts that act on a certain MarkLogic instance similar to using sql scripts with MySQl, say.

With liquibase,  [this maven plugin](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/maven) works great and I'm wondering if there's equivalent behavior built into some product for Marklogic.

The only Marklogic maven support I found was [here](https://github.com/ukcrpb6/maven-marklogic-plugin), but that doesn't seem to support the niceties of liquibase, such as not re-running scripts that are already run, rollback etc.

Thanks,
Pankaj

Based on Eric's suggestion, here's specifically what I'm looking for:

- Is there a way to store MarkLogic XQuery scripts into my code base and ensure that when I deploy the code base, the script is run if it is not executed in that environment, and not run, if it has.
- If I provide a "rollback" script, can this new product rollback to a given number of rollbacks say?

Comment: Liquibase is designed to support SQL based migrations. Not clear to me how something like MarkLogic would be supported

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help you, but note that

- MarkLogic has the ability to do point in time queries.
- You can tag (via collections) points in time if you so desire.
- Diffs will be challenging
- There is a set of API calls in XQuery (dls - Document Library Services) for versioning and control.

IMO, in order for you to get a useful answer, you should be specific about what features you want rather than just asking for all of liquibase.